# From...to goes to

Tags: forms-of-address

Is it correct to say from one place to **GOES** to another place INSTEAD of
FROM...TO...
Like in this sentence for example:
"We get arid climates in the center of Iran to **goes** to the south and southeast."

Answer (score 1):

No, ".. goes to..." can't replace "... from ... to ...". The following is grammatical:

We have arid climates from the center of Iran to the south and southwest.

Comment: Thank you so much